Chromium vs Firefox - android keyboard and viewport height overflow
It seems that Firefox / Webkit has different logic for handling viewport height when keyboard is open.
When I'm using Firefox browser (Android), everything looks fine, however on Chromium based browsers the site is not shrunking down (and a scrollbar appears).
How can I fix this CSS issue?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main style="min-height: 100dvh">
      <h1>Header</h1>

      <input
        type="text"
        style="position: fixed; bottom: 22px; width: 100%; height: 80px"
      />
    </main>
  </body>
</html>



I tried using svh and "normal" vh units, but nothing seems to work.
